# How to find all child images of a ReactInstance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-selectors, queryselectall

I'm the developer of [`react-to-print`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print), a React component printing library. Currently, to ensure images exist on the page before I open the print window, I load all images on the page identified by `document.querySelectorAll("img")`. However, for pages with lots of images this gets slow, and often most of the images are not within the React component being printed anyways, so don't need to be loaded for printing at all. Given a ReactInstance, how would I go about identifying all `img` tags that exist within the instance and all of its children?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("#react-root img")` ?

Comment: @azium the React root is not what I'm printing. I'm printing an arbitrary user provided Reach component from anywhere in the React tree

Comment: Can you not ask the user to provide the selector from which to do that? `document.querySelector(\`${parentSelector} img\`)`

Comment: @azium I could, though that would require exposing an additional prop on the API, and checking that the user does the correct thing with it. I'm hoping there is a way to avoid that. Ideally the user shouldn't need to know about how the internals of the library work.